# I have a somewhat complex SQL statement, but I don't know where to put the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I don't know where to put the WHERE clause.  In the driverstops table, I have a field called delivdate, and the table damagelog has a field called dateofdelivery.  I want to specify specific date ranges.  Where can I put the WHERE clause to limit the data?

```
SELECT 
    dr.drivername,
    sumStops,
    perfectcnt/sumStops * 100 AS perfpcnt,
    qualcnt/sumStops * 100 AS qualpcnt,
    compcnt/sumStops * 100 As comppcnt,
    damacnt/sumStops * 100 AS damapcnt,
    nofitcnt/sumStops * 100 AS nofitpcnt,
    incocnt/sumStops * 100 AS incopcnt,
    misscnt/sumStops * 100 AS misspcnt,
    notlcnt/sumStops * 100 AS notlpcnt,
    noupcnt/sumStops * 100 AS nouppcnt,
    failccnt/sumStops * 100 AS failcpcnt,
    failscnt/sumStops * 100 AS failspcnt,
    conccnt/sumStops * 100 AS concpcnt,
    nocodcnt/sumStops * 100 AS nocodpcnt,
    failicnt/sumStops * 100 AS failipcnt
FROM drivers dr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        driverid,
        SUM(numberofstops) sumStops
    FROM driverstops
    GROUP BY driverid
) stops ON dr.id = stops.driverid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        driverid,
        damagelog.dateofdelivery date,
        SUM(perfect) perfectcnt,
        SUM(quality) qualcnt,
        SUM(compliment) compcnt,
        SUM(damage) damacnt,
        SUM(nofit) nofitcnt,
        SUM(incomplete) incocnt,
        SUM(misseddeliv) misscnt,
        SUM(notloaded) notlcnt,
        SUM(noupdate) noupcnt,
        SUM(failcall) failccnt,
        SUM(failsendemail) failscnt,
        SUM(concerns) conccnt,
        SUM(nocod) nocodcnt,
        SUM(failinst) failicnt
    FROM damagelog
    GROUP BY driverid
) dam ON dr.id = dam.driverid
```

Comment: I imagine you could convey the gist of the problem in a simpler query.

Comment: If the columns to filter on are in joined tables, put the condition in the `ON` clause (as opposed to the `WHERE` clause). E.g. `LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM driverstops ... ) stops ON dr.id = stops.driverid AND delivdate BETWEEN ...`

Comment: Do tell what's the query suppose to do.  If you don't know where to put the `WHERE`, how do others, who don't know what the query is suppose to do, know where to put the `WHERE`?

Comment: @marekful  Unfortuantely that didn't work.

Comment: @Eric   I need the report to pull from 3 different tables.  The drivers table contains the names of the drivers.   The driverstops table calculates the number of stops for each driver for a given amount of time.  The damagelog table had various categories that indicated problems from deliveries.  I wanted to take the amount of problem (as seen in the xxxcnt aliases) and divided them by the  total number of stops for the driver, indicating a percentage.  I further wanted to be able to sort by the percentage to get an idea of which divers are performing the best in each category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as concerns, the columns that you want to filter on come from aggregated subqueries that are then `JOIN`ed. There is one join (`driverstops`) where the field you want to filter on is not returned by the subquery.

It seems like the simplest solution is to put a `WHERE` clause in each subquery, like :

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT driverid,SUM(numberofstops) sumStops
    FROM driverstops
    WHERE delivdate BETWEEN @stat_date AND @end_date
    GROUP BY driverid
) stops ON dr.id = stops.driverid
```

And :

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        driverid,
        damagelog.dateofdelivery date,
        SUM(perfect) perfectcnt,
        ...
    FROM damagelog
    WHERE dateofdelivery BETWEEN @stat_date AND @end_date
    GROUP BY driverid
) dam ON dr.id = dam.driverid
```

Comment: @Brian : welcome ! If my answer solved your problem, please *accept it* by clicking the green check... Thanks !